# MySQL: How to fetch by "New and Bestselling" like amazon?

Tags: mysql, sorting

In amazon.com, for instant, users can sort products by "New and Bestselling".

I have an "items" table which contains "uploaddate" column and "views" column for each item. How can I sort items by "New and Bestselling", combining uploaddate & views?

How can I modify this query to combine uploaddate & views to fetch items as "New & Bestselling"?

```
select * from items order by uploaddate desc, views desc
```

Comment: How do you want to combine the two columns? As an example, which item would be higher on this list: an item released yesterday with 500 views or an item released 2 days ago with 1000 views?

Comment: @bobby-w I don't know! Maybe the date should get higher priority than views, so maybe ratio of 1:3(date:views), so in your example, maybe yesterday/500 gets higher priority than 2days/1000

Comment: @evilReiko It sounds like the question you need to ask is how you _want_ to combine the two (that is, what formula you'd use), and then you can ask how to implement it. You're not limited by what you can do in a simple SQL query, either; if the formula gets complicated enough, you can just select all the records meeting a minimum criterion, pull the data into whatever framework you're using to do the query, and process it further there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways I can think of off the top of my head that could all be valid approaches.

1) Restrict the query to the last 7 days (or however you define "New") and just sort by views. This will ONLY show you new items, but it's the simplest.

2) Add a field that corresponds to how many weeks ago the item was added, and determine that by using a CASE statement. Like `SELECT CASE(WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE()-uploaddate) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS relative week` then sort by weeksort.

3) Like you suggested, as part of the select statement, use a formula to generate a ranking number based on the views and uploaddate fields, and sort by that. That's more difficult because ideally you want your rank to scale based on the maximum number of views and to heavily penalize older items so you don't have an amazingly popular item from 2 years ago at the top of the "New and Bestselling" chart.

Comment: 1 & 2 are sorting by date-then-views without combining, which is not what I'm looking for. 3 is exactly what I want, but it's not an answer, it's kindof like a rephrase of my question. Provide me a query example and I will give you a correct answer

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's a fair amount of extra work (as someone who has never done something like this before). I was simply trying to give you some considerations and suggestions of ways to approximate what you want to do. If you want more specific help, I'd suggest that you lay out exactly the behavior you want with some sample data. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would do two SELECT statements, one sorted by uploaddate and one sorted by views, then use UNION to merge them, then wrap them with another SELECT statement and group them to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I got your idea, but can you provide an example?